# How to increase the current output of a function generator?

Tags: current-source

I was wondering if someone could help getting me started.

I want to build a current amplifier that can amplify ~60mA to 10A while keeping the V_out = V_in.

This will be used to switch a power MOSFET (Qgate = 4050nC, Vgs_max = 15V) on and off with a square wave at 10V_peak, 1 microsecond pulse width and 25% duty cycle using a function generator.

Currently, the function generator can output 10V/(50ohm + 100 ohm) = 67mA or ~200mA with just R_internal = 50ohm.

There are already similar posts regarding the topic. However, they are mostly for much lower frequency than I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called a buffer amplifier, or unity gain amplifier. But if you're dealing with square waves, what you're really after is a MOSFET gate driver.

Comment: Hi Brian- I have looked at buffer amplifiers but can't put the pieces together (my background in electrical is very limited). With MOSFET, do you mean using another MOSFET with low Q_gate and a power supply with higher current?

Comment: the OPA541 if a beefy opamp that may work up to about 1MHz. But as Brian Drummond said for your specific application, you are after a mosfet driver,

Comment: No, it's a chip whose sole purpose is to drive a MOSFET gate because of the peculiar problems that involves.. There are thousands to choose from. For example https://uk.farnell.com/w/c/semiconductors-ics/power-management-ics-pmic/drivers-controllers/mosfet-drivers and filter for 10 Amps.

Comment: why can't you switch the fet directly with the fungen?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you! I didn't know such thing existed.

Comment: @dandavis The FG I'm using can't output enough current to charge the gate. With and without a 100Ohm resistor were 60mA and 200mA, respectively. From my calculation, I need at least 8A to achieve the switching speed of interest.